# What kind of test is that - checking interaction of two classes

Tags: testing, integration

There is a class A doing some calculations and class B, which is calling methods from the class A.
Unit tests were fine for both classes but when  used classes together, I discovered that it does not work. The issue was that the types of parameters were incorrect. As this was a part of school assignement, I was supposed to say what kind of test it is. I think it is an integration one, is that correct?

I think so because integration means integrating more modules into one system. And I am integrating two classes together here.

Answer (score 0):

Typically "integration test" means a test that touches some other system, like a database or file system or a web service or whatever. Since in your case it's two classes in the same program, I would categorize it as a unit test.

There's an expectation that a unit test have a small scope, but there isn't any hard and fast rule that it be limited to one method or one class.

Unit tests check that the code within the program is internally consistent, which is what needs doing here.

Comment: I was thinking about that as well but the defitions of integration test is "at least two modules" which seems to be this case. It is not unit because they are independent. I mean, it is one class calling the other one, which is not what a unit test should do.

Comment: @KhDonen: it depends on what a module is. If you have two pieces that stand alone (say one piece is a reusable library), then you can make a case for it being an integration test. If you'd never use these pieces separately (they would get combined into the same deployment artifact) then it is a unit test.

Comment: I always thought that a module is either a function, method or a class. Never heard about integration test using two classes.

Comment: Also one thing - you said "since it's two classes in the same program". That would mean even with 100 classes in one program, you would call it a unit test? Does not make sense, unit test should small piece of functionality, shouldn't it?

Comment: @KhDonen: unit tests can be whatever size is helpful, they're there to help the developer. so you can have some that have a very limited scope and others that are broader.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, a unit test would be one module (class) tested in isolation, with any external dependencies stubbed out.

But in reality, so-called unit tests will often break this rule. For example in Rails, unit tests often hit the database (but this can be avoided).

In the situation you describe here, 'integration' is probably the best term to use.

Note that the meaning of these terms can vary a lot depending on the context. I would call what Nathan Hughes describes a **system integration test** to distinguish it from more granular tests.